# Adding labels to BoxAnnotation in bokeh python

Tags: python, plot, charts, bokeh

I am plotting various scatter plots and added a BoxAnnotation to highlight a time period. Now I want to either label or add to the legend a description of what this BoxAnnotation represents. The relevant code is:

```
p = figure(title=plot_title, x_axis_label = 'Time(UTC)', y_axis_label= id,
                   x_axis_type = "datetime", plot_width = 700, plot_height = 300)
for comm in dsn_comms:
    low_box = BoxAnnotation(left = comm.start, right = comm.stop, fill_alpha = 0.1, fill_color = "#99FF99")
    p.add_layout(low_box)
d = p.circle(data_times, data_values, color = colors, line_color=None, size = 2)
```

The following graph is created:
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tdzK.png)

The green  sections are the ones I would like to label, the y axis varies so I can't hard code it and since it's not a glyph I can't add BoxAnnotation to the legend. Any ideas on what I could do?

Thank you.

Comment: If you use a patch glyph you can add it to the legend: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/glyphs/patch.html

Comment: @PJW I think the problem with the patch glyph is that I would have to define every point along the y axis, rather then just a left and a right